# Spring Security many providers

Tags: java, spring, spring-security

In my application I use LDAP authentication (called **ldap**). For one of my pages I need my own authentication with basic html popup (called **internal**). I get `BeanCreationException`:

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.security.filterChainProxy': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: A universal match pattern ('/**') is defined  before other patterns in the filter chain, causing them to be ignored. Please check the ordering in your <security:http> namespace or FilterChainProxy bean configuration
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1512) ~[spring-beans-3.2.5.RELEASE.jar:3.2.5.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:521) ~[spring-beans-3.2.5.RELEASE.jar:3.2.5.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:458) ~[spring-beans-3.2.5.RELEASE.jar:3.2.5.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:296) ~[spring-beans-3.2.5.RELEASE.jar:3.2.5.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:223) ~[spring-beans-3.2.5.RELEASE.jar:3.2.5.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:293) ~[spring-beans-3.2.5.RELEASE.jar:3.2.5.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:194) ~[spring-beans-3.2.5.RELEASE.jar:3.2.5.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:628) ~[spring-beans-3.2.5.RELEASE.jar:3.2.5.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:932) ~[spring-context-3.2.2.RELEASE.jar:3.2.2.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:479) ~[spring-context-3.2.2.RELEASE.jar:3.2.2.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:389) ~[spring-web-3.2.2.RELEASE.jar:3.2.2.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:294) ~[spring-web-3.2.2.RELEASE.jar:3.2.2.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:112) [spring-web-3.2.2.RELEASE.jar:3.2.2.RELEASE]
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4973) [catalina.jar:7.0.52]
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5467) [catalina.jar:7.0.52]
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150) [catalina.jar:7.0.52]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1559) [catalina.jar:7.0.52]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1549) [catalina.jar:7.0.52]
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source) [na:1.7.0_51]
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source) [na:1.7.0_51]
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source) [na:1.7.0_51]
at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source) [na:1.7.0_51]
```

Here is my configuration:

```
<http authentication-manager-ref="internal">    
    <intercept-url pattern="/monitoring" access="ROLE_USER" />
    <http-basic />
</http>

<http authentication-manager-ref="ldap" auto-config='true' use-expressions="true">
    <intercept-url pattern="/**" access="permitAll" />
    <form-login login-page='/' default-target-url='/login_ok'
        always-use-default-target='true' authentication-failure-url="/login_failed" />
    <logout logout-success-url="/" />
</http>

<authentication-manager id="internal">
   <authentication-provider>
       <user-service>
       <user name="monitoring" password="monitoring" authorities="ROLE_USER" />
       </user-service>
   </authentication-provider>
</authentication-manager>

<authentication-manager erase-credentials="false" id="ldap">
    <ldap-authentication-provider
        group-search-filter="${ldap.group-search-filter}" server-ref="ldapServer"
        group-search-base="${ldap.group-search-base}" user-search-filter="${ldap.user-search-filter}"
        user-search-base="${ldap.user-search-base}" group-role-attribute="${ldap.group-role-attribute}"
        role-prefix="${ldap.role-prefix}">
    </ldap-authentication-provider>
    <authentication-provider user-service-ref="userService" />
</authentication-manager>
```

I understand why the exception was thrown and know that patterns order and scopes are important, but have no idea how to do it correctly. All I want, is that every user has access to "/**", **but** only monitoring user has access to /monitoring (authenticated with basic). Everything worked just fine, before I wanted to add this internal authentication.

Answer (score 0):

The changes you need to make are:

- Ensure to have a pattern for the first `<http>`. This is the heart of your issue right now. Both `<http>` match every request, so the second `<http>` is never considered. To fix this, add the pattern attribute.
- Ensure to use a different role for your monitoring user. Remember, authentication and authorization are decoupled. This means that accessing /monitoring is only restricted by the role of the user NOT how the user authenticated. With the current setup, a user could authenticate to the ldap AuthenticationManager and if they were assigned the role "ROLE_USER" they could then visit /monitoring and see that URL.
- Although not necessary we update the intercept-url for the first `<http>` to match on every URL. This is not necessary since the first `<http>` is only used for the /monitoring URL in the first place, but it is a bit safer if someone updated the pattern attribute later on.

An example of the changes can be seen below:

```
<http authentication-manager-ref="internal" pattern="/monitoring">    
    <intercept-url pattern="/**" access="ROLE_MONITORING" />
    <http-basic />
</http>

<http authentication-manager-ref="ldap" auto-config='true' use-expressions="true">
    <intercept-url pattern="/**" access="permitAll" />
    <form-login login-page='/' default-target-url='/login_ok'
        always-use-default-target='true' authentication-failure-url="/login_failed" />
    <logout logout-success-url="/" />
</http>

<authentication-manager id="internal">
   <authentication-provider>
       <user-service>
       <user name="monitoring" password="monitoring" authorities="ROLE_MONITORING" />
       </user-service>
   </authentication-provider>
</authentication-manager>

<authentication-manager erase-credentials="false" id="ldap">
    <ldap-authentication-provider
        group-search-filter="${ldap.group-search-filter}" server-ref="ldapServer"
        group-search-base="${ldap.group-search-base}" user-search-filter="${ldap.user-search-filter}"
        user-search-base="${ldap.user-search-base}" group-role-attribute="${ldap.group-role-attribute}"
        role-prefix="${ldap.role-prefix}">
    </ldap-authentication-provider>
    <authentication-provider user-service-ref="userService" />
</authentication-manager>
```

One thing I would consider is moving the monitoring user into LDAP. Placing this user in an in memory instance encourages that user to no longer be maintained (i.e. password should be rotated regularly). This would also ensure you don't get any collisions between your LDAP users and the internal users (i.e. how do you know there isn't a user named "monitoring" in the ldap authentication?). Last it simplifies your configuration, you only need the single `<http>` configuration. If the HTTP Basic header is present, it will still authenticate using it.

Comment: Ok. Thing is, that http tag doesn't have path attribute, so there is an error in XML. Or meby I am missing some schema or something? And about rest - I agree, it could be better organised :).

Comment: Yep, I figured it out :). Changing "path" to "pattern" solved XML error, but when I want to access "/monitoring" I get 403 - Access Denied. No authentication form is shown, just error

Comment: Did you remember to change the role to ROLE_MONITORING for both the intercept-url and the monitoring user? Perhaps your browser is sending a different username / password automatically (http basic is remembered)? Did you try accessing it in incognito mode? What do the logs look like?

Comment: Yes, I changed role in both places. After clicking and logging many times I found, that when I open main page, type /monitoring, the popup shows, I enter correct credentials and I have access to /monitoring!

Comment: **But** when I go back to the main page and try to login using my form login (ldap credentials) I get another basic popup (?) asking for LDAP credentials. Looks like browser somehow remembers monitoring credentials and wants me to use BASIC login to confirm my LDAP credentials. Another thing is, when I log into LDAP on main page, logout (or not), and then type /monitoring, I get no popup and 403 I mentioned in previous comment.

Comment: There is really nothing you can do about the popup in the browser or the fact that browsers remember the HTTP basic dialog (this is the downside to using HTTP Basic). Would you like to support form based login and http basic (i.e. http basic used by an automated processes and form login for a user?). For the monitoring 403 issue you should post the debug logs when you get the 403

Comment: Ok. Sorry for not responding, but I had a lot work to do. Well I decided not to deal with problems, requested for LDAP role (as you mentioned) for specific accounts and now everything works fine with one (LDAP) provider. Thanks for good advices :)